# LTE (4G) - Is two (or multiple) antennas better than one?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, antenna-construction, antenna-system, phone

I have two antennas. A "multiband" (1710~2170 Mhz, 22 dBi)...

[image: "multiband" (1710~2170 Mhz, 22 dBi)]

...and a "fullband" (700~2600 MHz, 15dBi)...

[image: "fullband" (700~2600 MHz, 15dBi)]

Taking into account that my modem (router) is "fullband" and that it normally changes the frequencies in use according to the one that presents the best possible performance, I ask:

#### Will I have better performance using these two (or multiple) antennas together?

**NOTE:** If yes, I would like some guidance on how I can go about doing this.

**Thanks!**

**PLUS:** I will use an N Female to 2 N Female jack adapter...

[image: N Female to 2 N Female jack adapter]

[Ref(s).: https://proeletronic.com.br/produto/antena-celular-tri-band-22dbi/ , https://proeletronic.com.br/produto/antena-celular-fullband-pqag-5015lte/ , https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001786488827.html ]

Comment: Just a note: for the public, the useful part of the link to the item on AliExpress ends with the .html extension - it is always better to cut the rest beginning with the questionmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out which frequencies are used by LTE in your region, your country, by your cell provider. Also which bands and frequencies your modem is capable of. It will likely use the most modern system available to it, so no need to cover the oldest bands it could theoretically use.

This will tell you whether a particular antenna could work at all for your modem.

It would be quite unusual to use such a high gain / narrow beam dish antenna for LTE though. The LPDA is more appropriate from that point of view. The LPDA isn't 15 dBi, it will be about 10 dBi at best, before the cable loss. That's still plenty of gain for LTE, especially as it will be mounted outside on a pole where the signal is stronger.

You definitely don't want to connect two antennas together with a T-piece. That would first create an impedance mismatch leading to unwanted reflection of power both transmitted and received. It will also create a very strange radiation pattern, very unlikely to improve on one antenna alone, and changing very quickly over angle and frequency.

LTE generally will benefit from installing two antennas, *connected with two cables to the two antenna ports of the radio*. They should be mounted either cross-polarised or separated by a few wavelengths, to take full advantage of the MIMO features of the system. There are XPOL and twin antennas available commercially for this purpose.

Comment: So I could have two `"fullband" (700~2600 MHz)` antennas (model shown, "yagi") attached to the pole "separated by a few wavelengths". So I ask "few wavelengths" would be how much distance in centimeters, for example? **Thanks!** 

Comment: I thought of the hypothesis of obtaining two units of the model (LPDA) in the link and mounting them in the MIMO and XPOL scheme. **Do you think it's a good idea?**
https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/1005001913807403.html?spm=a2g0o.ppclist.product.120.22defFEdfFEdNa&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21BRL%21R%24%20204%2C96%21R%24%20153%2C74%21%21%21%21%21%402101f6b116738311333695164ed697%2112000018116822583%21btf&_t=pvid%3Aeaf5fe2d-8cee-42c8-a2cf-0ea0277c4e3f&afTraceInfo=1005001913807403__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1673831133&gatewayAdapt=glo2bra
**Thanks!** 

Comment: **Example:** Two Yagi 4G LTE Antennas in XPOL
https://assets.onbuy.com/i13/product/e9dbe323dace4f8b8aeb3d40722c953a-m10656230/antennas-4g-lte-wifi-log-yagi-11dbi-7008009001800210024002600-mhz-lowcostmobile-2x10m-duo-sma-black-cable-wl240-for-huawei-b525-b528.jpg

Comment: Yes that's not a yagi, they have a single boom and are quite narrowband, not good for LTE. The LPDA pictures you show look suitable. And yes - you can mount them at +- 45 degrees, or mount them both for vertical and space them about 0.5 to 1 m apart. Google for more detail. This video might be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPZ-rkX-eHw

Comment: Something important here is that the modem (router) needs to have MIMO (**for LTE**) capability. Normally they will have two antennas or more. Eg.: http://www.suportewnc.com.br/especificacoes-tecnicas/ .