# LTE (4G) - Which external/outdoor antenna type is the best?

Tags: antenna-theory, antenna-construction, antenna-system, phone

I've seen several antenna types out there, but I can't know for sure which model is the best for external/outdoor LTE (4G) use.

I have to say that I don't understand anything about LTE (4G) antennas...

**PARABOLIC (*MIME is possible with two?*)**

[image: PARABOLIC]

**LPDA(❓) (*MIME is possible with two?*)**

[image: LPDA(?)]

**LPDA (in XPOL) (MIME)**

[image: LPDA (in XPOL)]

**FLAT PANEL (XPOL) (MIME)**

[image: FLAT PANEL (XPOL)]

### QUESTION: What is the best type for external/outdoor LTE (4G) use?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Anyone? Any idea? 

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This, sadly, is a product recommendation question, and these are explicitly off-topic :(

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't understand how it can be a "product recommendation", since I'm not talking about manufacturers, just antenna types that can be manufactured by anyone. Someone might say "LPDA" is better for this reason or that... I respect your opinion, but I have to disagree. 

Comment: @Community There are added questions because certain antenna models can be used via MIME. The community is using a generic rule that is not considering any context.